# How do I make WireMock verification more informative?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assert, wiremock

I'm writing some unit tests for a wider test framework that uses Rest Assured. The test framework is implementing a DSL as a fluent API and I want some unit tests to prove the code behind the API is doing what it should, i.e. calling a web service when required.

I'm using WireMock to simulate the applications the test framework will ultimately be accessing. I have the test framework successfully reaching WireMock and verifying the reqeusts using WireMocks's `verify`. What I can't see is how to get WireMock's `verify` to log a message when it fails in the same manner that you can for a regular assertion.

Regular assertion example:

```
Assert.assertNotNull("The thing was null", thing);
```

The above will result in the following being logged if `thing` is null:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The thing was null
```

With WireMock I'm verifying with code like this:

```
verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/api/product")));
```

If the code being tested doesn't make a request to that path then I only get the following logging:

```
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: No requests exactly matched. Most similar request was:
```

Is it possible to give WireMock a meessage to log when a verification fails?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for this for a long time ago, and tried to make it using a Kotlin extension function but didn't get to make it, because all verify methods returns void :(. 
It's a good feature if we can have it integrated to WireMock. 
Regards